# It's about semi colon at the end of a class

Tags: c++

If we are declaring a member function inside the class but defining it outside the class then what about the semi colon after the closing of class

Comment: Not sure what the question is - you still need a semicolon after the declaration, if that's the question.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Wherever you decide to define your member functions, a class definition must end with a semicolon. Are you placing semicolons at the end of your member function definitions too?

Comment: You need to review the difference between a function *declaration* and a function *definition*.

Answer (score 3):

A contrived example showing which bits need `;` and which bits don't:

```
class Point
{
    int x; // Member variable declarations need terminating with ;
    int y;
public:
    int getX (); // Member function declarations need terminating with ;
    int getY ();
}; // Class declaration needs terminating with ; , even if the function definition follows

int Point::getX ()
{
    return x;
}  // Member function definition doesn't have a terminating ;
```

Hope this answers your question but if not, clarify the question.